# How to get values from enclosing elements in JAXB

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have the following XML structure:

```
<PriceBook>
    <PriceList product="0D000000.007C.06">
        <Price .../>
        <Price .../>
    </PriceList>
    ...
</PriceBook>
```

A `PriceList` holds a list of `Price` objects. I don't want that `Price` objects have back references to their `PriceList`s.

**Question:**

I would like to have the product information not only set in my `PriceList` objects, but *also* in the `Price` objects. Of course I don't want to have that duplication in the XML itself, only on Java side. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: You want `price` objects to have the `product` attribute from the containing `priceList` but don't want that attribute to show up when you marshal?

Comment: Can you provide the domain objects you want to map to this XML document?

Comment: The `product` attribute should only show up on `PriceList` level in XML, as all `Prices` in a `PriceList` belong to the same `product`. However for handling on the Java side it's convenient to have this information on the `Price`s as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage an `afterUnmarshal` event on the `PriceList` object.  In this event you could iterate over the list of `Price` objects and set the product information.  You would need to mark the product information on `Price` to be @XmlTransient.

**For More Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/MOXy/Runtime/Events

Comment: Stupid me, I was too focused on solving this somehow with annotations. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the actual solution is backwards: The list of prices isn't set yet when `afterUnmarshal` is called in `PriceList`, but if you put `afterUnmarshal` in `Price`, you can get the `PriceList`as parent parameter.